# Question feed has too-narrow questions with lots of whitespace

Tags: bug, android-app

On my tablet, the question feed has a ridiculous amount of whitespace between the questions, and the questions themselves have extremely narrow frames, often too narrow for one word to fit on a single line.
[image: screenshot of my question feed]
Now, I do realize that my device, a Polaroid L9, isn't a very popular model, so it may be difficult to test for. I suspect that this may have something to do with a discrepancy between the device's physical dimensions and actual resolution/dpi, and the display size (s/m/l/xl) and density (ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/vhdpi) that the device reports itself as having - I suspect that it's actual resolution is on the low side, and it likes to use some custom rendering to "fake" a higher resolution, because, for example, the stock home screen displays all app icons properly, but the Google Now Launcher displays some apps' icons as slightly "out of focus", as if it uses the next smaller size icon resource and scales it up.
Anyway, everything else in the app looks perfectly normal, but this issue occurs regardless of orientation and whether the left-hand tray is expanded or collapsed.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Southern Telecom
- Device Model: L9

  - OS Version: 5.0 (1437224297)